# Python: Working with dataframes of different sizes to create new columns based on datetime conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 2 dataframes of different sizes in Python. The smaller dataframe has 2 datetime columns, one for the beginning datetime and one for the ending datetime. The other dataframe is bigger (more rows and columns) and it has one datetime column.

df A

```
Date_hour_beginning   Date_hour_end
3/8/2019 18:35        3/8/2019 19:45
4/8/2019 14:22        4/8/2019 14:55
```

df B

```
Date_hour         compression
3/8/2019 18:37      41
3/8/2019 18:55      47
3/8/2019 19:30      55
3/8/2019 19:51      51
4/8/2019 14:10      53
4/8/2019 14:35      48
4/8/2019 14:51      51
4/8/2019 15:02      58
```

I want to add the mean and amplitude of compression to df_A that cover the datetime range. To get the following result:

```
df_A
Date_hour_beginning   Date_hour_end     mean_compression     amplitude
3/8/2019 18:35        3/8/2019 19:45        47.66              14
4/8/2019 14:22        4/8/2019 14:55        49.5               3
```

I tried the np.where and groupby but I didn't know but I had the error of mismatching dataframe shapes.

Comment: Where do the values in `amplitude` come from?

Comment: It's the highest minus lowest value. 55-41 for the first row and 51-48 for the second one.

Comment: Could you provide the files or code to create those dataframes? So that we don't have to recode everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. It is kind of a more verbose (and maybe more readable?) version of eva-vw's. eva-vw's uses the `.apply()` method which is the fastest way of looping over the rows of your dataframe. However it should only make a significant difference in run time if your `df_A` has really many (many) rows (which does not seem to be the case here).

```py
for i, row in df_A.iterrows() :

    start = row['Date_hour_beginning']
    end = row['Date_hour_end']

    mask = (df_B['Date_hour'] >= start) & (df_B['Date_hour'] <= end) 
    compression_values = df_B.loc[mask, 'compression']

    df_A.loc[i, 'avg comp'] = compression_values.mean()
    df_A.loc[i, 'amp comp'] = compression_values.max() - compression_values.min()
```

For completeness, here is how I created the dataframes:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Date_hour_beginning', 'Date_hour_end']

times_1 = pd.to_datetime(['3/8/2019 18:35', '3/8/2019 19:45'])
times_2 =  pd.to_datetime(['4/8/2019 14:22', '4/8/2019 14:55'])

df_A = pd.DataFrame(data=[times_1, times_2], columns=columns)

data_B = [ ['3/8/2019 18:37',      41],
            ['3/8/2019 18:55',      47],
            ['3/8/2019 19:30',      55],
            ['3/8/2019 19:51',      51],
            ['4/8/2019 14:10',      53],
            ['4/8/2019 14:35',      48],
            ['4/8/2019 14:51',      51],
            ['4/8/2019 15:02',      58]]

columns_B = ['Date_hour', 'compression']
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data=data_B, columns=columns_B)

df_B['Date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['Date_hour'])
```

To go a bit further: to solve your problem, you need to loop over the rows of `df_A`. This can be done in three main ways: (i) with a plain `for` loop over the indices of the rows of the dataframe, (ii) with `for` loop with the `.iterrows()` method, or with the `apply()` method.

I ordered them from the slowest to the fastest at runtime. I picked method (ii) and eva-vw picked method (iii). The advantage of `.apply()` is that it is the fastest, but its disadvantage (to me) is that you have to write everything you want to do with the row, in a one-line `lambda` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Presenter!! Your code works:)) But why Eva's .apply is giving me : KeyError: ('compression', 'occurred at index 0')  ?

Comment: See my comment below eva-vw's answer, hope it helps. More readable code is also easier to debug, that's why I opted for my solution! Once you're satisfied with an answer, don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# create test dataframes
df_A = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date_hour_beginning": ["3/8/2019 18:35", "4/8/2019 14:22"],
        "Date_hour_end": ["3/8/2019 19:45", "4/8/2019 14:55"],
    }
)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date_hour": [
            "3/8/2019 18:37",
            "3/8/2019 18:55",
            "3/8/2019 19:30",
            "3/8/2019 19:51",
            "4/8/2019 14:10",
            "4/8/2019 14:35",
            "4/8/2019 14:51",
            "4/8/2019 15:02",
        ],
        "compression": [41, 47, 55, 51, 53, 48, 51, 58],
    }
)

# convert to datetime
df_A['Date_hour_beginning'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['Date_hour_beginning'])
df_A['Date_hour_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['Date_hour_end'])
df_B['Date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['Date_hour'])

# accumulate compression values per range
df_A["compression"] = df_A.apply(
    lambda row: df_B.loc[
        (df_B["Date_hour"] >= row["Date_hour_beginning"])
        & (df_B["Date_hour"] <= row["Date_hour_end"]),
        "compression",
    ].values.tolist(),
    axis=1,
)

# calculate mean compression and amplitude
df_A['mean_compression'] = df_A['compression'].apply(lambda x: sum(x) / len(x))
df_A['amplitude'] = df_A['compression'].apply(lambda x: max(x) - min(x))
```

Comment: Thanks Eva! While running the accumulation, I got this:
KeyError: ('compression', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Hmm that would happen if you didn't have the `compression` column in `df_B`, but you do right?

Comment: Added code to create the dataframes, lmk if your data looks different

Comment: You are right. I have different files. I need to apply your solution on my files now!

Comment: Should the comma after "compression"  in `.apply()` not be removed? Maybe that solves it?

Comment: @presenter the comma is just a formatting artifact, wouldn't be causing OP's KeyError.

Comment: I would try to remove the formatting on the apply line to turn it into a single line. My guess is that something was messed up when copying it out of here. Anyway, like @presenter said in their answer this is really just a one-line alternative to using iterrows.

Comment: Hello Eva, The first .apply worked. But when I use your last lines to calculate the mean and amplitude, I get an error of divisibility by zero. That's because in some rows, there are no values to include, so the some of the len(x) was equal to zero. Is it possible to add an if x!=0 to your last 2 lines of code? Also, in the last line. I got this error:ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sure you can add `if len(x) != 0 else np.nan` to the end of each of those lambdas (will need to `import numpy as np`)

Comment: Works like a charm:) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
df_A['Date_hour_beginning'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['Date_hour_beginning'])
df_A['Date_hour_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['Date_hour_end'])
df_B['Date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['Date_hour'])

df_A = df_A.assign(key=1)
df_B = df_B.assign(key=1)
df_merge = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on='key').drop('key',axis=1)

df_merge = df_merge.query('Date_hour >= Date_hour_beginning and Date_hour <= Date_hour_end')
df_merge['amplitude'] = df_merge.groupby(['Date_hour_beginning','Date_hour_end'])['compression'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
df_merge = df_merge.groupby(['Date_hour_beginning','Date_hour_end']).mean()
```

Output:

```
                                         compression  amplitude
Date_hour_beginning Date_hour_end                              
2019-03-08 18:35:00 2019-03-08 19:45:00    47.666667       14.0
2019-04-08 14:22:00 2019-04-08 14:55:00    49.500000        3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, Luigigi! The pd.merge didn't work. It gave me a memory error.

Comment: It didn't specify. Just some colorful codes and memory error at the end:/

Answer (score 1):

groupby can accept series equally indexed, i.e.

```
df['Date_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_hour'])

df_a['begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['begin'])
df_a['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['end'])

selector = df.apply(lambda x: df_a.query(f'begin <= \'{x["Date_hour"]}\' <= end').index[0], axis=1)

for i_gr, gr in df.groupby(selector):
    print(i_gr, gr)
```

And then go on with your .mean() or .median()